# How to include the result of a call to an object in a math expression?

Tags: r

I'm having a hard time using the `expression()` function for adding text to a plot. Specifically, I have been unable to use the result of a call to an object within the expression. Here's an example:

#### Example

```
set.seed(1)
x <- 1:100
y <- 2*x + 3 + rnorm(length(x), sd=10)

fit <- lm(y~x)
plot(y~x)
abline(fit)
text(50,200, labels=expression(paste(alpha, "=", round(fit$coeff[1],3), "; ", beta, "=", round(fit$coeff[2],3), "; ", R^2, "=", round(summary(fit)$r.squared,2))))
```

[image]
I would like the text to look like what is written in red in the figure.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `?bquote`,

```
text(50,200, label=bquote(alpha == .(fit$coeff[1]) ~ "; "~ beta == .(fit$coeff[2])~"; "~R^2 ==  .(summary(fit)$r.squared)))
```

Comment: Nicely answered, but-- where are things like the tilde to separate actual quoted material documented? The help page only covers `.()` .

Comment: plotmath's missing alias, `?trialanderror`. I tried with `*` but got an error, next thing was the tilde.

Comment: @baptiste thanks-- I played around and found that anything defined as a symbol in plotmath, like `>` , will serve to separate items, and realized as well that `label=bquote(alpha ==.(paste(blahblahblah)))` allows the `paste` command to operate as one would hope.